# Enforce all custom posts have specific custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a custom post, whenever someone creates a new instance of this post I want to add some custom fields to it. Whats the easiest way to do such a thing?

Is detecting the post creation `save_post` and call `add_post_meta` to add the custom fields? Or is there a better/easier way? Maybe I can register the custom fields at the time I register the custom post?

Comment: Hooking into `save_post` and setting a meta field sounds like a good solution. Does this value need to change? Is the author supposed to set a custom value?

Comment: Will the custom fields be the same for each custom post? If so, why not use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin? Or is there more to this?

Comment: @Matthew we looked into this but that means using lots of plugins, because  project uses vue.js we will need another plugin to serve the advanced custom fields via a RESTful request (because ACF doesn't do that does it?)

Comment: @kero we will always have the same fields for each post; title, video url, etc. The author sets these fields for each custom post instance.

Comment: ACF doesn't add the custom fields to the REST API out of the box, however there is a plugin that adds that functionality: [ACF to REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/)

Comment: You pretty much nailed the answer in your question with the second paragraph. ACF is more for creating flexible content, and adding UI for fields, rather than automating adding post meta as you describe. It might be that it adds a field to the UI with a default value that gets saved on the first save, which sort of does what you want